# create numbered files with defined content with bash

Tags: bash, scripting

I want to create 69 files with a filename from 4006 through to 7075 and it each file needs to have some enumerated content, the following code prints on the shell what I would like to have inserted into the respective files but how do I do this?

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 4006 4075`; do
      echo "vid $i\nports 524288\nactive = 1 >vlan_$i.ini"
done
```

I have tried to put the part between quotes into ` (back ticks) but then I just get empty files.

Comment: `for i in $(seq 4006 4075); do echo "vid ... = 1" >"vlan_$i.ini"`

Comment: @mikeserv answer my question wit this line and i'll accept, only that i hhad to use `printf` instead of `echo` for the new lines `\n` - Thanks!

Comment: Gilles's answer is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to redirect the output of the `echo` command, the redirection operator `>` needs to be outside of any quotes. The character `>` between double quotes stands for itself.

By default, in bash, `echo` doesn't expand backslash sequences. You need to pass the `-e` option to `echo`, set the `xpg_echo` shell option with `shopt`, or use `printf` instead of `echo`.

```
for i in `seq 4006 4075`; do
  printf "vid %s\nports %d\nactive = 1\n" "$i" 524288 1 >"vlan_$i.ini"
done
```

A [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) is a more readable 
way to represent a multiline string. Since it's passed as input rather than as a command line argument, use `cat` instead of `echo`. Note that if the text is indented, the indentation is copied (you can avoid that with `<<-EOF` instead of `<<EOF` but you can only use tabs to indent, not spaces).

```
for i in `seq 4006 4075`; do
  cat <<EOF >"vlan_$i.ini"
vid $i
ports 524288
active = 1
EOF
done
```